# using functions from ninja-forms says that the function doesnt exist

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

When I try to use this function from ninja forms i get an error that the function doesn't exist.

```
$d = ninja_forms_get_fields_by_form_id('1');
```

What is the proper way to call this function or other functions from their documentation? is there an action that must be used?

the error that i get is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ninja_forms_get_fields_by_form_id() in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone has this issue I resolved it by including this into the php file

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
```

and that loads all of wordpresses functions into the php file so that i can use anything and it'll work.